# How can I add a class to each radio button of value < current value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have a JQueryUI slider. The value of the slider is set by clicking one of 5 radio buttons, and the same works in reverse- moving the slider selects a radio button.

I want to add a class "checked" to each radio button equal to and lower in value than the current value of the slider, and to remove the class if it is present in higher-value radio buttons- IE, I want to achieve the following mark-up, if the slider has a value of "2":

```
<div class="column size10">
    <div class="slider" id="smoker" data-begin="0" data-end="4"></div>
    <input type="radio" class="smoker_radio checked" name="[smoker]" value="0" id="smoker[1]"/>
    <input type="radio" class="smoker_radio checked" name="[smoker]" value="1" id="smoker[2]"/>
    <input type="radio" class="smoker_radio checked" name="[smoker]" value="2" id="smoker[3]"/>
    <input type="radio" class="smoker_radio" name="[smoker]" value="3" id="smoker[4]"/>
    <input type="radio" class="smoker_radio" name="[smoker]" value="4" id="smoker[5]"/>
</div>
```

I am passing the value of the slider to a function, checkRadio. See [JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/uYgCg/1/)

What's the best way to check for this and assign the class to the correct radio buttons?

-- Update --

There's a JSFiddle linked above- here's how I am passing the slider value to function checkRadio():

```
//When radio buttons are changed, update slider 
$('[name="[smoker]"]').change(function () {
    var value = this.value;
    $('#smoker').slider("value", value);
    checkRadio(value);
});

//When slider is changed, update radio buttons 
$('#smoker').on('slidechange', function () {
    var value = $(this).slider('value');
    $('[name="[smoker]"][value="' + value + '"]').prop("checked", true);
    checkRadio(value);
});

function checkRadio(val) {
  var value = val;
  console.log(value)

}
```

Comment: Can you show the code that you use to initialise your slider? Perhaps with a [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) that we can experiment, and work, with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
function checkRadio(val) {
  var value = val;
    $('input.smoker_radio').removeClass('checked');
    $('input.smoker_radio').each(function(){
        if( $(this).val() <= value){
            $(this).addClass('checked');
        }
    });
```